# How to delete at the same time from both parent and child table

Tags: postgresql

Say I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."parent" (
  parent_id UUID not null,
  name TEXT not null,
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."child" (
  child_id UUID not null,
  parent_id UUID not null,
  name TEXT not null,
  CONSTRAINT "child_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("parent_id") REFERENCES "public"."parent"("parent_id")
)
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent_id IN (DELETE FROM child WHERE name LIKE '%whatever' RETURNING parent_id)
```

This query returns syntax error. Although returning from delete query is possible so inside query is ok, meaning surrounding query can't work this way.

*Also could someone please explain why the above query isn't possible?*

Comment: It does not work because of the `... WHERE name LIKE '%whatever'`. You are not deleting all the child records that have the `parent_id`, so when you delete the parent record with the `parent_id` it fails as there are still child records that reference it.

Comment: Also just noticed this `... REFERENCES "public"."parent"("company_id")`. There is no `company_id` in the `parent` table.

Comment: The reason why the query won't execute:
When you use the DELETE statement with a RETURNING clause in the subquery, it returns the values of the deleted rows. However, the IN operator expects a set of values or a subquery that returns a set of values, not a subquery that returns a result set.

Answer (score 1):

You need a CTE ("common table expression").  Your current formulation isn't possible because it returns a syntax error.  I don't think there is any profound reason for that.

```
with d as (DELETE FROM child WHERE name LIKE '%whatever' RETURNING parent_id) 
DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent_id IN (select * from d)
```